# Finding types after ilmerge

Tags: .net, reflection, ilmerge

Let's say that I do ilmerge on assembly1 and assembly2.

Can I use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetTypes()` from assembly1 to find a type in assembly2 when running the merged assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the types are now contained in a new assembly which has been rewritten the executing (assembly of the declaring type) is the new assembly.

If you try to run the code you should see that it works fine.